# HTTP 404 from Web Api service while trying to post document with metadata from httpclient

Tags: .net, post, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I am trying to post a document with metadata from a httpclient to a WebAPI service.

Here is the client code snippet which is trying to do a post -

```
protected async void PostContent(byte[] flStream)
                {
                    using (var client = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:45757/");
                        DocumentDetails docObj = new DocumentDetails();
                        docObj.entId = "ent_1";
                        docObj.docContent = flStream;

                        HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(docObj));
                        HttpResponseMessage response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage();
                        response = await client.PostAsync("api /AppServices / CreateDoc", content);
                    }
                }
```

Here is the server side code -

```
         [Route("CreateDoc")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CreateDoc(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        HttpContent requestContent = Request.Content;
        string jsonContent = requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        DocumentDetails dc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DocumentDetails>(jsonContent);
        return  new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
     }
```

I cant figure out what is wrong in the server side code.
When I try to debug using the client side code, I receive status code as NotFound.

Can anyone of you please point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have spaces in your client.PostAsync URL

Comment: Good observation really...removing the spaces now giving me http 500 error now. Even though I have the service running I can not see the debugger stopping anywhere on the service.

Comment: You should be able to debug your service.  The 500 error indicates you could be crashing in the call.

Comment: You're stating that the Route is "CreateDoc". Have you tried calling client.PostAsync("CreateDoc", content)?

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this would not work as the client module would not be able to find the service without the full path name.